# how do I avoid the startup delay when I connect to a MySQL database using c# system.data.mysqlclient visual-studio on mac

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, database-connection

Is there a way to force sql connection when the connection is open.. For the first time I wait 20 seconds to display the data.. after that everything is ok..

I use `system.data.mysqlclient` library for connect to cloud sql.

The code:

```
void Btn_GetPlaces(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string cs = @"server=192.168.0.1,3306;userid=Alex;password=Alex123;database=DBMeteo";

        var connection = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        connection.Open();
        LabelSQL.Text = "Connection has beed sucsessfully..";
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = connection;

        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand($"CALL nearest3({GlobalLat}, {GlobalLong}, 1)", connection);

        using (MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // access your record colums by using reader
                LabelPlace.Text = (reader[0]).ToString();
                LabelDist.Text = (reader[1]).ToString();
                LabelCode.Text = (reader[2]).ToString();
            }
        }

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        LabelSQL.Text = (ex.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're asking the wrong question.  The right question is "how do I avoid the startup delay when I connect to a MySQL database?"  There is no concept of "forcing a database connection."

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42277370) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/144492/mysql-connection-is-slow-5seconds).  It would seem the first thing to try is checking your reverse DNS.